# drupal 7, paths and urls are not working properly

Tags: url, drupal-7

I'm developing a website based on drupal on my localhost. I have a problem with urls.

for a url like this :

```
http://localhost:81/my_website/library
```

I must output image src this way :

```
<img src="<?php print $directory; ?>/image/header/headerR.png"/>
```

but when the above url is changed to this

```
http://localhost:81/my_website/library/
```

I must output image src this way :

```
<img src="../<?php print $directory; ?>/image/header/headerR.png"/>
```

I mean it must refer to the parent. my website has contextual filter which can be inserted
after **library/** .is there any general solution for handling such thing?

Comment: try using <img src="<?php print base_path() . path_to_theme() ?>/image/header/headerR.png" /> it that should work in most D7 environments.
base_path() pulls the base path from the settings.php if it's set
[API Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/base_path/7). path_to_theme() pulls the path to the default theme, you can also pass through a specific theme [API Link](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/path_to_theme/7).

Answer (score 0):

If you are printing an image directly to html you must use a non relative path to move to other dirs. You must always start the image path with /, so the image is relative to the domain, in this case, localhost. Example

```
<img src="/<?=$whatever; ?>" />
```

Also try building the image in the Drupal way. See these functions:

```
theme_image
theme_image_style
image_style_url
```

Use any of them, as you need.
Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

use only relative path and put theme related images into your theme folder

lets say that your theme is named YOURTHEME
when you do `<img src="/image/header/headerR.png"/>`
it should load image from `http://localhost:81/sites/all/themes/YOURTHEME/iamge/header/headerR.png`

but if you need to load images from different than theme directory you will need to use CDN module https://drupal.org/project/CDN
you will be also able to load images easily from other server, its usefull when working on local DEV and getting images from production server